# Keep running into errors with the Google Cloud API

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Recently I have been working with the Google Cloud API for some data analysis projects. Currently I keep following instructions from other websites and make my own dataset based off that. I keep running into errors with the Google Cloud API however.

For example, I'm trying the method from the following article: https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/data-science/how-to-query-the-google-search-console-api-with-ecommercetools

However, Python responds with the following:

> Error:  Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields token_uri, client_email.

I created basic credentials under 'OAuth 2.0 Client IDs' as mentioned in the article.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
from ecommercetools import seo
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 100)

key = "G:\Python Projects\query_gsc_secrets.json"
site_url = "https://startselect.com/"
start_date = "2019-01-01"
end_date = "2020-12-31"

print(key)


payload = {
    'startDate': start_date,
    'endDate': end_date,
    'dimensions': ["page"],
    'rowLimit': 10000,
    'startRow': 0
}

df = seo.query_google_search_console(key, site_url, payload)
df.sort_values(by='clicks', ascending=False).head()
```

The reason why I'm asking this is because this error seems to be recurring in one form or another. Am I missing something when creating credentials? Is there a mistake in the code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the format of the key is not as expected.

You've mentioned you created the basic credentials under the "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" but if you read through [the linked article](https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/data-science/how-to-access-the-google-search-console-api-using-python), you can see that the API expect a service account key.

Service account key format looks like this:

```
{
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "project-id",
"private_key_id": "key-id",
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivate-key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "service-account-email",
"client_id": "client-id",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url": 
"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-account-email"
}
```

Which matches the format requested in the error
`missing fields token_uri, client_email.`

In this GCP documentation you can read how to [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) and  [service account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-list-console)